# removing space between two div inline

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I have a two  which they are inline . there is space between them , how can I remove the space between two

```
  <div class="d-inline pl-5" style="float:left">
       <div class="showborder d-inline" style="padding:0 !important;margin:0 !important">test1</div>
       <div class="showborderblue d-inline" style="padding:0 !important;margin:0 !important">test2</div>
  </div>
```

and this is CSS, to show the space between the divs I have set border

```
 .showborder {
   border: 2px solid red;
 }

 .showborderblue {
   border: 2px solid blue;    
 }
```

The result is like this:

[image]

I want the red line to stick to the black line. and remove the space between Test1 and test2

Comment: Remove the whitespaces inside your html might help, or remove the `float: left` on the parent element and set it to `display: flex`.

Might be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-do-i-remove-the-space-between-inline-inline-block-elements

Comment: change the parent to `d-inline-flex` and remove `d-inline`  from children

Comment: I think you can probably change the Gutters to either `g-0` (all sides) or `gy-0` (left and right only). Here is a better explanation.... https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/gutters/